# Long-Lasting EMP Effect?

Tags: electricity, radiation

What kind of Event / Device / Natural Phenomenon could possibly avert the use of electronics in an area for a longer period of time? I have nuclear radiation (low-level) available, if that helps (fictional of course).

I'll elaborate: The field(?) or whatever makes the use of electronics in a certain area impossible. The effect is longlasting (centuries). It doesn't have to be a real phenomenon, but at least somewhat plausible.

No antimatter please :)

Comment: What about an asteroid containing lots of radioactive elements crashed into Earth forming a thick layers of iridium isotopes rendering all electronic devices in that region unreliabe. You may like to substitute iridium with other appropriate radioactive substances for extra potency it should emits lots of beta particles, vagabond electron or positron (oops sorry looks I mentioned antimatter but you mentioned nuclear radiation which contradicts your condition for omitting antimatter:)

Comment: I think your main problem isn't the 'disable electronics for a long time' issue. This question had come up before, and the problem was more that most such methods will also kill everyone in the area within a short period of time.

Comment: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/17922/8602 is related

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lack of or globally weakened or locally weakened magnetosphere on the planet would expose the planet surface to increased ionizing radiation/charged particles. It's a well known issue that large enough  solar events could compress the Van Allen belts sufficient to induce current in electronic devices and fry them.

Or the magnetosphere could be fine but the star goes through some kind of freak, once in 100 million year solar maximum that lasts for a hundred years where the solar wind is constantly high with lots of solar flares and coronal mass ejection play merry hell with the magnetosphere.

Comment: That would make it impossible to retain an electrical infrastructure for distribution like we have now, (and would cause worse problems for us!) but local electronics could work and be shielded against "events".

Comment: True, electric distribution grids would fail and fail quickly. Humans starting to explore electricity from first principles would adapt to the circumstances they found themselves in.

Comment: Could this be a local effect? Like a certain only a certain piece of ground is affected?

Comment: @openend, is this effect something you want to be able to start and stop or can it be a permanent area denial effect?

Comment: permament would be preferable. Whatever works :)

Answer (score 3):

"EMP" by definition, is a singe *pulse* of very-high-level EM radiation, powerful enough to incite havok in nearby electronics. As stated, nuclear explosions can create EMP, and over a large area. But to do so continuously, would take a massive amount of power. EMP can be created artificially in some other ways, but typically involve high power and physically large components, even for small EMP bursts. Does it have to run *continuously*? If it could "go off" every few minutes, that would be more realistic, as whatever massive thing it was would have time to "charge up" between pulses. What would be the point of say, booting a computer, when it would crash before the login screen came up? Every... time... Imagine the frustration!

A recent television show named "Revolution" was based around the idea of sustained denial of electricity. In the show, it was caused by nanites, microscopic machines which reproduced out of control and swamped everything on the planet, literally absorbing all of the (electrical) energy they could find.

Comment: It wouldn't have to go off every minute. A large pulse that fried all electronics worldwide would require years, probably decades before computers came back to today's level — it takes electronics to build electronics! But to last centuries, that's not enough: someone would invent a way to shield against that EMP source, if it becomes a fixture.

Answer (score 0):

**Permanent Electronics Area Denial**

To achieve permanent area denial for the use of unshielded electronic equipment, requires some kind of power source. Other answers use a star or man-made power sources, delivering area denial in periods ranging from seconds to centuries.... But we want a permanent area denial.

A [magnetar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetar) creates a hellishly strong magnetic field for approximately 100,000 years before going inactive. The magnetic fields generated are quadrillions times stronger than earths magnetic field. Were a planet placed sufficiently close, the magnetar would definitely disrupt any and all unshielded electronic equipment on an effectively permanent basis. But not too close because the magnetic fields are strong enough to make the chemistry of life impossible.